# RotateAnimation get current angle

Tags: android, imageview, rotateanimation

Any tricks to get RotateAnimation current angle? I've an imageview that is rotate with RotateAnimation, imageview.getRotation() is always 0.0. Maybe it's a trick to get the rotation angle ?
Thaks

Comment: You are mixing the old and the new animation api. Use `view.animate().rotate(45);` or `view.setRotation(45);` and then `getRotation()` will return the right angle.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use SensorEvent or Position Sensor for get rotation angle.

This is help for SensorEvent [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html)

This is help for PositionSensors [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/sensors/sensors_position.html)

I hope this is help you.